# Is there an event in ios for user canceling a local notification?

Tags: ios, events, notifications

Is there an event I could catch in my app when a local notification -that my app presented- has been canceled by the user?

I found no indication in the documentation that something like this exist but maybe there is some workaround? Or am I missing something?

Maybe staying in background keeping a reference to the local notification and periodically checking for a property that changes when notification is canceled?